# How can i remove that on top view?

Tags: modeling

[image: The arrow shows what im talking about]

I cant see the background with this.

Answer (score 3):

If that is indeed a background image, you can set it draw under or over everything, in your case it is currently set to draw behind everything, to change that, Press <kbd>N</kbd> while in 3D view, and scroll down to background images, you will find two buttons, one labeled Back, and the other Front, by default it is set to Back:

[image: Back mode]

We want to change that to Front, like so:

[image: Front mode]

Answer (score 0):

Hit the Z key to activate wireframe mode and then disable faces in the mesh display tab under the right sidebar (wich you can open by hitting N)

Comment: i just printed this way to show what im talking about, cuz i was editing on wireframe mode, but still hard to edit this way.